# How to fix "Expected static method" WebClient Vertx in java

Tags: vert.x

I need help with webclient vertx in java.

Implementation as is in the manual in java, however gives an error in the:  WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx);

Make a project to test the Vertx WebClient. So it's not big, so it has the same Main class.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx); 
}
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expected static method io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.VersionCommand.getVersion()Ljava/lang/String;
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.WebClientOptions.loadUserAgent(WebClientOptions.java:499)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.WebClientOptions.(WebClientOptions.java:46)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.WebClient.create(WebClient.java:55)
    at Main.Main.main(Main.java:15)

I couldn't solve it. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: This actually worked for me, what is your vertx version? Also, make sure that the imports are `import io.vertx.core.Vertx;` and `import io.vertx.ext.web.client.WebClient;`

Comment: I use version vertx-web-client 3.8.1, and version vertx-core 3.3.3. I made the imports as you said. What's your version?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. The vertx-core version was different from vertx-web-client. I changed the version of vertx-core to 3.8.1 in pom.xml and it worked. Thank you.